# How can I solve this program

Tags: java, loops

Implement a static method that takes a int number as parameter, uses Math class to calculate the integer square root of a given integer. If the integer is negative take square root of its positive then return negative of result to imply it is an imaginary number

I attempted and reached until here

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int j = 1, result = 1;

System.out.println("Enter a number : ");
int x = in.nextInt();

if (x == 0 || x == 1 ) 
{
  System.out.println("Square root = " + x);
  return;
}

while (result <= x) 
{
  j++;
  result = j * j;
}

System.out.println("Square root = " + (j - 1));
```

Comment: This is Java. Javascript and jQuery are not in anyway relevant. Also, please give a more descriptive title which explains the problem you have

Comment: It is stated that you should use `java.lang.Math.sqrt()`

Comment: I don't see reference to class [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) in the code in your question. You are meant to use it to calculate the square root, aren't you? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? We find the square root of the number and ensure the input number is positive. Math.abs will find the absolute value. We then return the result as negative if the input was negative, otherwise return the square root.

```java
    static int result(int input) {
        int result = (int) Math.sqrt(Math.abs(input));

        return input < 0 ? -result : result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default

> Math.sqrt()

already Handles the square root of all positive numbers .But when you try with a negative number you get "NaN". Therefore you need to implement negative numbers on your own

```
  public static double getRoot(int num) {
    boolean isNegative = false;
    // if negative turn to positive int
    if (num < 0) {
        num = Math.abs(num);
        isNegative = true;
    }

    double result = Math.sqrt(num);
    if(isNegative) {
        // Negate number
        result = 0 - result;
    }

    return result;
```